# Thread access static variable cause segmentation error

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm trying to compare performance of methods about adding two matrix.
one method is just to add.
the other method is to use threads.

but I have a trouble about segmentation error when a thread access a static variable!

Here is my code.

**main.c**

```
#include "matrixProcessor.h"

void main()
{

    time_t s0, e0;
    int i;
    int status;

    inputVec1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(SIZE*SIZE));
    inputVec2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(SIZE*SIZE));
    outputVec = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(SIZE*SIZE));

    srand(time(NULL));

    initializeVector(inputVec1);
    initializeVector(inputVec2);

    //printf("=== INPUT VECTOR 1 ===\n");
    //printVector(inputVec1);
    //printf("=== INPUT VECTOR 1===\n");
    //printVector(inputVec2);

    //s0 = clock();
    //addVec(inputVec1, inputVec2, outputVec);
    //e0 = clock();

    //printf("Basic Method Time : %f (s)\n",(double)(e0-s0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    s0 = clock();

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {   
        printf("%d-Thread Call\n",i);

        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &addProc, (void*)&i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    e0 = clock();

    printf("=== OUTPUT VECTOR===\n");
    printVector(outputVec); 

    printf("Thread Method Time : %f (s)\n",(double)(e0-s0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    free(inputVec1);
    free(inputVec2);
    free(outputVec);

}
```

**matrixProcessor.c**

```
#include "matrixProcessor.h"


void initializeVector(int* matPtr)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE*SIZE ; i++)
    {
        matPtr[i] = rand()%100;
    }
}

void addVec(int* inputVec1, int* inputVec2, int* outputVec)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE; i++)
    {
        outputVec[i] = inputVec1[i] + inputVec2[i];
    }
}

void* addProc(void *p)
{
    int* idx = (int*)p;
    int count = (SIZE * SIZE) / NUM_THREAD;
    int i;

    printf("idx value : %d\n",*idx);
    printf("Test : %d ", inputVec1[0]);

    for(i = (*idx) * count  ; i < (*idx)*count + count; i++)
    {
        outputVec[i] = inputVec1[i] + inputVec2[i];

    }
    return NULL;
}

void printVector(int* vec)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", vec[SIZE * i + j]);          
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**matrixProcessor.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define NUM_THREAD 10

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];

static int* inputVec1;
static int* inputVec2;
static int* outputVec;

void initializeVector(int* matPtr);

void printVector(int* vec);
void addVec(int* inputVec1, int* inputVec2, int* outputVec);
void* addProc(void *p);
```

when compiling, i use -static - lpthread options.

I'm sure that accessing static variable cause segmentation error,
because this program prints some messages before reaching a code line which access static variable.

Here is result.

```
0-Thread Call
idx value : 0
Segmentation Error! ./main
```

Please someone help me..!

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>`, don't cast the return value of `malloc` and compile with warnings. Also, sending `&i` into the thread will not do what you think it does (the thread might get a much later value of `i`).

Comment: static makes your variable only accessible in the the current file (kinda like private), so your static variables are 2 different variables in each file, I think. Why do you want it to be static in the first place? Wouldn't it be enough to be global?

Comment: Explaination for Kami Kaze comment: You have **two instances** of `inputVec1` pointer variable, both are *defined* in `matrixProcessor.h`. Code in `main.c` uses *the first* instance: it initializes it with `malloc()` call. Code in `matrixProcessor.c` uses *the second* instance of the variable, and this variable is not initialized. So, when trying to dereference that variable's instance, you get "Segmenration Fault".

Comment: Thanks Art, but I think `malloc` returns address of memory and gcc doesn't show me warning about it but segmentation error...

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right. I miss that point. so I have to define thread function and static variable in the same file.
Actually, I confused with JAVA so I don't need static. sorry

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.  The two that jump right out to me are listed below.

First, this one:

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &addProc, (void*)&i);
```

What's the value of `i` when the child thread accesses it?  It can be anything, because it changes as the main thread spawns more threads and continues to run.

Second, what do you think these `free()` statements do when they're executed *while the child threads are still running*:

```
free(inputVec1);
free(inputVec2);
free(outputVec);
```

When your code makes those calls, the child threads are still running since you don't call `pthread_join()` to make sure they've all completed.

You likely get the segmentation violation because your threads are accessing `free()`'d memory.

Comment: Thanks Henle! I solve these